# IAP refund policy

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am now setting up IAP in my app and all is running fine in the sandbox environment.

The products in my app are consumable products. Users will post ads on my website once the purchase is successful. The ads on my website has a limited time (I.e. It will expire after 20 days).

If users purchase the products in my app and the ads are posted on my website, after some days, say 14 days (I've heard that users can request a full refund in the first 14 days without specifying any reasons), they request for a refund from Apple. Then this undoubtedly affects my apps revenue and Apple seems to provide no measures or policy to protect the developers.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: there is no way to prevent it. you have to trust in your customers.

Comment: There's so safe guards against this. Simply make sure your IAP price is justified by the quality of what you're selling. It's rare that a user requests a refund in my experience. I have only had 1 in the past year and I sell multiple IAP everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a range of legal requirements in various countries, Apple are required to provide a "change of mind" refund on both App and In-App purchases. As an App vendor, you're agreeing to this in the various documents you "sign" to become so. That basically means you have to absorb any loss that may occur from this (such as you describe). Luckily this doesn't seem to currently be a major issue, and as long as your IAP pricing is reasonable, you shouldn't expect to encounter this on a regular basis. I suppose in some ways you can consider this the digital equivalent of shoplifting. It's something that will probably happen to a very small degree, but if your prices are good, and the environment is friendly, it's far less likely to happen.